# I have written this piece of code and I know it can be reformatted, in order to look cleaner, but I don't know how. Could anyone help me?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new at programming and I would like some insights in how to make it cleaner. This is part of a monthly expense program.
1

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class JanelaDespesa(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.geometry('300x100')
        self.title('Despesa')

        ttk.Button(self,
                   text='Fechar',
                   command=self.destroy).pack(expand=True)


class JanelaReceita(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.geometry('300x100')
        self.title('Receita')

        ttk.Button(self,
                   text='Fechar',
                   command=self.destroy).pack(expand=True)


class JanelaRelatorio(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.geometry('300x100')
        self.title('Relatório')

        ttk.Button(self,
                   text='Fechar',
                   command=self.destroy).pack(expand=True)


class JanelaModificar(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.geometry('300x100')
        self.title('Modificar Dados')

        ttk.Button(self,
                   text='Fechar',
                   command=self.destroy).pack(expand=True)


class TelaPrincipal(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry('700x200')
        self.title('Tela Principal')

        ttk.Button(self,
                   text='Lançar Receita',
                   command=self.open_window1).pack(expand=True)

        ttk.Button(self,
                   text='Lançar Despesa',
                   command=self.open_window2).pack(expand=True)

        ttk.Button(self,
                   text='Relatório',
                   command=self.open_window3).pack(expand=True)

        ttk.Button(self,
                   text='Modificar Dado',
                   command=self.open_window4).pack(expand=True)

    def open_window1(self):
        window = JanelaReceita(self)
        window.grab_set()

    def open_window2(self):
        window = JanelaDespesa(self)
        window.grab_set()

    def open_window3(self):
        window = JanelaRelatorio(self)
        window.grab_set()

    def open_window4(self):
        window = JanelaModificar(self)
        window.grab_set()


app = TelaPrincipal()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written far more code than you really need.

Consider this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from functools import partial

class Janela(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, geometry='300x100'):
        super(Janela, self).__init__(parent)
        self.geometry(geometry)
        self.title(title)
        button = ttk.Button(self, text='Fechar', command=self.destroy)
        button.pack(expand=True)


class TelaPrincipal(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TelaPrincipal, self).__init__()
        self.geometry('700x200')
        self.title('Tela Principal')
        control = [
            ('Lançar Receita', 'Receita'),
            ('Lançar Despesa', 'Despesa'),
            ('Relatório', 'Relatorio'),
            ('Modificar Dado', 'Modificar')]
        for text, title in control:
            ttk.Button(self, text=text, command=partial(self.open_window, title)).pack(expand=True)

    def open_window(self, title):
        Janela(self, title).grab_set()


app = TelaPrincipal()
app.mainloop()
```